# How to determine week number with 1st day as 1st Monday of February in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a requirement to calculate week number, which is very similar to fiscal week but the week counting has to start from first monday of February. The week starts from Monday and ends on a Sunday.

For example - 02/03/2020 (mm/dd/yyyy so 3rd Feb 2020) should be the first date of the first fiscal week of 2020 i.e. first monday of the month of Feb is the start date.

I know there are solutions out there where we assume Feb 1 as equivalent to Jan 1 to start counting of the fiscal week however, in this case the ask to start from the 1st monday of Feb.

02/01/2020, 02/02/2020 would fiscal week 53 of 2019 while 02/03/2020 would be fiscal week 1 of 2020.

```
=WEEKNUM(A3-31,10+WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(A3-31),1,2),2))
```

With the updated formula, it should calculate 12/17/2020 as 46 (above formula calculates it to 47) while 06/14/2020 should calculate to 19.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the `LET` formula in Office 365 we can use:

```
=LET(x,DATE(YEAR(A3),2,7)-WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(A3),2,1)-1,3),y,DATE(YEAR(A3)-1,2,7)-WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(A3)-1,2,1)-1,3),z,IF(A3<x,y,x),WEEKNUM(A3-(z-DATE(YEAR(z),1,1)),10+(WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(z),1,1),2))))
```

Without it:

```
=IF(A3<DATE(YEAR(A3),2,7)-WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(A3),2,1)-1,3),WEEKNUM(A3-(DATE(YEAR(A3)-1,2,7)-WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(A3)-1,2,1)-1,3)-DATE(YEAR(A3)-1,1,1)),10+WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(A3)-1,1,1),2)),WEEKNUM(A3-(DATE(YEAR(A3),2,7)-WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(A3),2,1)-1,3)-DATE(YEAR(A3),1,1)),10+WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(A3),1,1),2)))
```

We need to use a different base date which is the second part

Comment: This is perfect and seems to work with the examples I tested for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is the first monday of feb (lets say this is in B3):

```
=DATE(YEAR(A3),2,1)+MOD(8-WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(A3),2,1),2),7)
```

then the fiscal week is

```
=WEEKNUM(A3,2)-weeknum(B3,2)+1
```

This is quite fool proof, but simple enough.

Comment: How does this work other years, for example, 1/16/2021 resolves to 02/01/2021 (1st Feb of 2021 which is correct) however this would still be a part of the previous fiscal year as it is before 02/01/2021, so it should resolve to week no. = 50. But with the above formula it resolves to -2. Same for 02/01/2020 where is resolves to 0 which in fact should be 52 of last year i.e. 2019.